# How to build a native mobile app for a joomla site

Tags: mobile, joomla

I am about to build a mobile app using html5 with phonegap. So that i can easily install it on any platform. Android, Blackberry or ios.

I want this app to be able to perform CRUD - in close connection with my joomla site.

The Joomla site is already completed, its a social network. I need this app to be able to retrieve information such as profile pictures, messages e.t.c and then be able to upload pictures, send messages and use the geolocation api.

My question is i dont know how to make the app connect or communicate with my Joomla db.

Comment: You need a web developer to create an API component for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i found the answer, just in case anyone needs it.
To build a mobile using Joomla as the server, what you need is
1. Jquery
2. Build an extension on your Joomla site
3. Using the jquery ajax methods + Joomla's native method to provide data in Json format, you can build an api to send and receive data from your mobile app to your joomla website.

Comment: Yes - more information greatly appreciated. How do you handle user login and registration, sessions etc. ?